# xcode display data from json web service

Tags: ios, json

I am using a web service used to display details about person and profile but I don't know how to display the data from web service to labels. I have worked with login validation using web service the code is as below

```
 -(IBAction)login:(id)sender
  {
     NSString *username=userName.text;
     NSString *password=passWord.text;
     if ([username length]!=0&&[password length]!=0)
     {
         NSString *link=[NSStringstringWithFormat:@"http://www.abcd.com/XXX/YYY/Login.ashx/?Username=%@&Password=%@",username,password];
         NSURL *URLGet= [NSURL URLWithString:link];
         NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URLGet]; 
         NSError* error;
         XYZ Return array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
     if ([jasonReturnArray  isEqual: @"UserId 4"]) 
     { 
         Connections *view2=[[Connections alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; 
         view2.modalTransitionStyle= UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
         [self presentViewController:view2 animated:NO completion:nil]; 
         NSLog(@"%@",jasonReturnArray); 
     } 
     else 
     { 
         UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR !!!!!!"message:@"Wrong Details" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"otherButtonTitles: nil];
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
         NSLog(@"%@",jasonReturnArray); 
         [alert show]; 
     }
 }
 else 
 {
 UIAlertView* alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR !!!!!!"
 message:@"Wrong Details" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO]; 
 NSLog(@"%@",jasonReturnArray);
 [alert show]; 
} 
}
```

It works fine but my doubt is

**how to display the data from json web service to my designed labels**

Comment: There are many Threads for this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=objective-c+parse+json And also check IBOutlet for UILabel in objective-c

Comment: Every things depend on your web service if 'jasonReturnArray' has string objects then you can easily set that , if it has NSDictionary objects then you can grab every part of your data with its 'KEY'.

Comment: yeah in string objects without any keys means how to get it in label i mean i wanna display each strings in different labels

Comment: your array have single object or multiple ?

Comment: sorry it does not have any arrays after login service i have to display person details while selecting details button. But the service for button includes only strings there are no array{}in that

Comment: they have provided details only through strings with no keys and arrays

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80156/discussion-between-gopinath-and-m-david).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create IBOutlet of your UILabel then set text value of your label as following

```
for (NSString * singleStringObject in jasonReturnArray)
    {
        yourLabel.text=[yourLabel.text stringByAppendingString:singleStringObject];
    }
```

in case of single string you just set text of `yourLabel` without any loop.

Comment: it is getting crashed by unrecognized selector indicating for statement

Comment: Have you checked the IBOutlet  is properly connected to your UILabel?

Comment: i got the link with keys and arrays and displayed in xib labels.. Another doubt is how can i print an empty string in UI ex: for address:"" how can i print it in uilabel

Comment: before set UILabel.Text check the NSString.length if length = 0 then update NSString with @"None" OR @"--". 
e-g if(address.length==0){
address=@"None" OR address=@"--";
}
UILabel.text=address;